# convertir string a jsonArray generado por DataSnap en php

Tags: php, javascript, angular7, delphi

buen día:
tengo una función PHP, que llama a mi servidor DataSnap:

```
  $consulta = $DataSnap.'tabla2json'.$qweryData;
  $contents = file_get_contents($consulta);
```

Donde $datasnap es la URL, tabla2json el servicio y $qweryData los parametros, me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
{"result":[[{"eventid":"7E426-B63A","fecha":"2020-02-06T11:09:48.384","cliente":"GRUPO NECAXA","area":"Proteccion","cancelado":false,"tracking":0},{"eventid":"7E3314-D1A25","fecha":"2019-03-20T13:29:42.566","cliente":"HELADOS IGLU","area":"Proteccion","cancelado":false,"tracking":3},{"eventid":"7E421B-D2013","fecha":"2020-02-27T13:35:39.658","cliente":"TELAS MEXICO","area":"Proteccion","cancelado":false,"tracking":0}]]}
```

Cuando hago `var_dump()` de la respuesta me dice que es un string. La pregunta es: ¿Cómo le devuelvo este string a caller?, en este caso, es una funcion js que espera un jsonArray.

Estoy empezando a experimentar con angular y quiero aprovechar todo lo que ya tengo desarrollado en mi DAtaSnap Server.

Comment: ¿Cómo realizas la interacción entre PHP y Javascript? A fin de cuentas, solo necesitas un `echo` pero depende de que el contenido lo devuelvas a una llamada AJAX o crees directamente una variable en un documento HTML (o contexto) donde tu "caller" pueda acceder a ella.

Comment: Porque no simplemente devuelves con un echo como dice @Triby el JSON resultado?, despues de todo si espera un JSON array entonces no lo asignes directamente desde JS al obtener la respuesta, simplemente al parsearlo deberas usar tu propiedad result de tu objeto, de esa manera tendras un JSON array, no hace falta complicarlo mas debido a que considero que el JSON que tienes es totalmente valido.

Comment: [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) convierte una cadena o array a JSON. En PHP se usa esa función para devolver JSON al cliente.

Comment: Gracias Triby, estoy utilizando Angular 9 para desarrollar el FrontEnd, desde ahí en el ngOnInit, le paso los parámetros de la consulta que etiqueté como $qweryData, y espero como respuesta un json, el problema realmente es que al objeto que genera mi Servidor DataSnap, le agrega el prefijo "{"result":[" (como puedes ver en mi pregunta) y al querer hacer echo $respuesta, me manda un error PHP Sorry. soy programador de la vieja escuela (cobol, pascal) estoy apenas aprendiendo

Comment: @hugofernandez, en la pregunta no aparece la variable `$respuesta`, por eso es importante incluir todo el código involucrado. Por favor edita tu pregunta para incluir cómo estás enviando el resultado desde PHP y cómo lo manejas en javascript, de otra forma, solo estaremos adivinando. P.D. También soy de la vieja escuela y sigo aprendiendo.

Comment: Gracias Triby, el código completo php sería:   $consulta = 
                     $DataSnap.'tabla2json'.$qweryData;
                    $contents = file_get_contents($consulta);$respuesta= json_Encode($contents); echo($respuesta).

Comment: te comento que solucioné el problema, utilizando la función substr() para eliminar el prefijo "{'result': [" y el"]}" del final, funciona perfectamente, pero creo que no es la forma "elegante" de hacerlo.